# How to copy marklogic document into unix host location

Tags: javascript, marklogic

I have developed a javascript which uses cts.search on Marklogic host and returns a json. I want to save this document into a unix host location. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So basically you want to save a JSON locally on your Server. That should be no big deal. What have you tried? What did not work?

Comment: https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp.save

Comment: Thanks @MichaelGardner, it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`xdmp.save`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp.save) can save the document to the file system where MarkLogic is running. If you want to save it somewhere else, you'll need to make an HTTP call from there and run a search, then save the results with whatever you use to make the HTTP call.

If that doesn't address what you're looking for, please expand your question so we know better what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Great! Please mark this answer as "Accepted" to get it off the unanswered list